# How to do skeletal detection in swift using Vision framework

Tags: ios, swift

I am building an app that does skeletal detection using swift.Now that we have achieved skeletal detection and display for a single image, we would like to do the same for video.
However, I have no idea how to do skeletal detection for video.I am thinking that I should take frames from the video and make a judgment for each frame, but I have not been able to get it down to code.We would appreciate your wisdom.

The following is a program that performs skeletal detection on an image. (Sorry for the messy code, I'm a beginner.)

```
import UIKit
import Vision

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var imageView1: UIImageView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
     
    let windowSize_w = imageView1.bounds.width
    let windowSize_h = imageView1.bounds.height
     
    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.videoPlayer)

    let image = UIImage(named: "sample.jpg")!
    imageView1.image = image
    poseDetect(image)
     
    func poseDetect(_ image:UIImage){
      // 処理したい画像（フレーム）を保持する関数
      //let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage:(imageView1.image?.cgImage)!)
      let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage:image.cgImage!)
      // 画像中の人物の骨格情報を推定するもの（モデル含む？）
      let poseEstimationRequest = VNDetectHumanBodyPoseRequest()
       
      do {
        // poseEstimationRequestを使ってimageRequestHandlerの画像を解析する
        try imageRequestHandler.perform([poseEstimationRequest])
      } catch {
        print("error")
      }
      
      guard let results = poseEstimationRequest.results as? [VNHumanBodyPoseObservation] else{
        return
      }
       
      do {
        for obserbation in results {
          // 顔
          let nose = try obserbation.recognizedPoint(.nose).location
          let rightEye = try obserbation.recognizedPoint(.rightEye).location
          let rightEar = try obserbation.recognizedPoint(.rightEar).location
          let leftEye = try obserbation.recognizedPoint(.leftEye).location
          let leftEar = try obserbation.recognizedPoint(.leftEar).location
          let neck = try obserbation.recognizedPoint(.neck).location
           
          // 右腕
          let rightShoulder = try obserbation.recognizedPoint(.rightShoulder).location
          let rightElbow = try obserbation.recognizedPoint(.rightElbow).location
          let rightWrist = try obserbation.recognizedPoint(.rightWrist).location
           
          // 左腕
          let leftShoulder = try obserbation.recognizedPoint(.leftShoulder).location
          let leftElbow = try obserbation.recognizedPoint(.leftElbow).location
          let leftWrist = try obserbation.recognizedPoint(.leftWrist).location
           
          // 腰
          let root = try obserbation.recognizedPoint(.root).location
           
          // 右脚
          let rightHip = try obserbation.recognizedPoint(.rightHip).location
          let rightKnee = try obserbation.recognizedPoint(.rightKnee).location
          let rightAnkle = try obserbation.recognizedPoint(.rightAnkle).location
           
          // 左脚
          let leftHip = try obserbation.recognizedPoint(.leftHip).location
          let leftKnee = try obserbation.recognizedPoint(.leftKnee).location
          let leftAnkle = try obserbation.recognizedPoint(.leftAnkle).location
          
          let nose_x = nose.x * windowSize_w
          let nose_y = (1 - nose.y) * windowSize_h
          let nose_cir = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: nose_x, y: nose_y), radius: 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2.0), clockwise:true)
          let nose_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          nose_lay.path = nose_cir.cgPath
          nose_lay.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
          nose_lay.lineWidth = 3.0
           
          let rEye_x = rightEye.x * windowSize_w
          let rEye_y = (1 - rightEye.y) * windowSize_h
          let rEye_cir = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: rEye_x, y: rEye_y), radius: 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2.0), clockwise:true)
          let rEye_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          rEye_lay.path = rEye_cir.cgPath
          rEye_lay.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
          rEye_lay.lineWidth = 3.0
           
          let lEye_x = leftEye.x * windowSize_w
          let lEye_y = (1 - leftEye.y) * windowSize_h
          let lEye_cir = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: lEye_x, y: lEye_y), radius: 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2.0), clockwise:true)
          let lEye_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          lEye_lay.path = lEye_cir.cgPath
          lEye_lay.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
          lEye_lay.lineWidth = 3.0
           
          let rEar_x = rightEar.x * windowSize_w
          let rEar_y = (1 - rightEar.y) * windowSize_h
          let rEar_cir = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: rEar_x, y: rEar_y), radius: 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2.0), clockwise:true)
          let rEar_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          rEar_lay.path = rEar_cir.cgPath
          rEar_lay.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
          rEar_lay.lineWidth = 3.0
           
          let lEar_x = leftEar.x * windowSize_w
          let lEar_y = (1 - leftEar.y) * windowSize_h
          let lEar_cir = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: lEar_x, y: lEar_y), radius: 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2.0), clockwise:true)
          let lEar_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          lEar_lay.path = lEar_cir.cgPath
          lEar_lay.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
          lEar_lay.lineWidth = 3.0
           
          let neck_x = neck.x * windowSize_w
          let neck_y = (1 - neck.y) * windowSize_h
          let neck_cir = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: neck_x, y: neck_y), radius: 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2.0), clockwise:true)
          let neck_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          neck_lay.path = neck_cir.cgPath
          neck_lay.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
          neck_lay.lineWidth = 3.0
           
          let RS_x = rightShoulder.x * windowSize_w
          let RS_y = (1 - rightShoulder.y) * windowSize_h
          let RS_cir = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: RS_x, y: RS_y), radius: 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2.0), clockwise:true)
          let RS_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          RS_lay.path = RS_cir.cgPath
          RS_lay.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
          RS_lay.lineWidth = 3.0
           
          let RE_x = rightElbow.x * windowSize_w
          let RE_y = (1 - rightElbow.y) * windowSize_h
          let RE_cir = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: RE_x, y: RE_y), radius: 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2.0), clockwise:true)
          let RE_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          RE_lay.path = RE_cir.cgPath
          RE_lay.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
          RE_lay.lineWidth = 3.0
           
          let RW_x = rightWrist.x * windowSize_w
          let RW_y = (1 - rightWrist.y) * windowSize_h
          let RW_cir = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: RW_x, y: RW_y), radius: 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2.0), clockwise:true)
          let RW_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          RW_lay.path = RW_cir.cgPath
          RW_lay.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
          RW_lay.lineWidth = 3.0
           
          let LS_x = leftShoulder.x * windowSize_w
          let LS_y = (1 - leftShoulder.y) * windowSize_h
          let LS_cir = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: LS_x, y: LS_y), radius: 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2.0), clockwise:true)
          let LS_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          LS_lay.path = LS_cir.cgPath
          LS_lay.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
          LS_lay.lineWidth = 3.0
          
          let LE_x = leftElbow.x * windowSize_w
          let LE_y = (1 - leftElbow.y) * windowSize_h
          let LE_cir = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: LE_x, y: LE_y), radius: 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2.0), clockwise:true)
          let LE_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          LE_lay.path = LE_cir.cgPath
          LE_lay.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
          LE_lay.lineWidth = 3.0
           
          let LW_x = leftWrist.x * windowSize_w
          let LW_y = (1 - leftWrist.y) * windowSize_h
          let LW_cir = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: LW_x, y: LW_y), radius: 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2.0), clockwise:true)
          let LW_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          LW_lay.path = LW_cir.cgPath
          LW_lay.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
          LW_lay.lineWidth = 3.0
           
          let RO_x = root.x * windowSize_w
          let RO_y = (1 - root.y) * windowSize_h
          let RO_cir = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: RO_x, y: RO_y), radius: 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2.0), clockwise:true)
          let RO_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          RO_lay.path = RO_cir.cgPath
          RO_lay.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
          RO_lay.lineWidth = 3.0
           
          let RH_x = rightHip.x * windowSize_w
          let RH_y = (1 - rightHip.y) * windowSize_h
          let RH_cir = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: RH_x, y: RH_y), radius: 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2.0), clockwise:true
          let RH_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          RH_lay.path = RH_cir.cgPath
          RH_lay.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
          RH_lay.lineWidth = 3.0
           
          let RK_x = rightKnee.x * windowSize_w
          let RK_y = (1 - rightKnee.y) * windowSize_h
          let RK_cir = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: RK_x, y: RK_y), radius: 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2.0), clockwise:true)
          let RK_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          RK_lay.path = RK_cir.cgPath
          RK_lay.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
          RK_lay.lineWidth = 3.0
           
          let RA_x = rightAnkle.x * windowSize_w
          let RA_y = (1 - rightAnkle.y) * windowSize_h
          let RA_cir = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: RA_x, y: RA_y), radius: 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2.0), clockwise:true)
          let RA_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          RA_lay.path = RA_cir.cgPath
          RA_lay.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
          RA_lay.lineWidth = 3.0
           
          let LH_x = leftHip.x * windowSize_w
          let LH_y = (1 - leftHip.y) * windowSize_h
          let LH_cir = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: LH_x, y: LH_y), radius: 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2.0), clockwise:true)
          let LH_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          LH_lay.path = LH_cir.cgPath
          LH_lay.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
          LH_lay.lineWidth = 3.0
           
          let LA_x = leftAnkle.x * windowSize_w
          let LA_y = (1 - leftAnkle.y) * windowSize_h
          let LA_cir = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: LA_x, y: LA_y), radius: 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2.0), clockwise:true)
          let LA_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          LA_lay.path = LA_cir.cgPath
          LA_lay.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
          LA_lay.lineWidth = 3.0
           
          let LK_x = leftKnee.x * windowSize_w
          let LK_y = (1 - leftKnee.y) * windowSize_h
          let LK_cir = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: LK_x, y: LK_y), radius: 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2.0), clockwise:true)
          let LK_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          LK_lay.path = LK_cir.cgPath
          LK_lay.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
          LK_lay.lineWidth = 3.0
           
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(nose_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(rEye_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(rEar_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(lEye_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(lEar_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(neck_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(RS_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(RE_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(RW_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(LS_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(LE_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(LW_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(RO_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(RH_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(RK_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(RA_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(LH_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(LK_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(LA_lay)
           
          let RStoRE_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          RStoRE_lay.lineWidth = 2.0
          RStoRE_lay.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
          let path1 = UIBezierPath()
          path1.move(to: CGPoint(x: RS_x, y: RS_y))
          path1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: RE_x, y: RE_y))
          RStoRE_lay.path = path1.cgPath
           
          let REtoRW_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          REtoRW_lay.lineWidth = 2.0
          REtoRW_lay.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
          let path2 = UIBezierPath()
          path2.move(to: CGPoint(x: RE_x, y: RE_y))
          path2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: RW_x, y: RW_y))
          REtoRW_lay.path = path2.cgPath
           
          let RStoLS_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          RStoLS_lay.lineWidth = 2.0
          RStoLS_lay.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
          let path3 = UIBezierPath()
          path3.move(to: CGPoint(x: RS_x, y: RS_y))
          path3.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: LS_x, y: LS_y))
          RStoLS_lay.path = path3.cgPath
           
          let LStoLE_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          LStoLE_lay.lineWidth = 2.0
          LStoLE_lay.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
          let path4 = UIBezierPath()
          path4.move(to: CGPoint(x: LS_x, y: LS_y))
          path4.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: LE_x, y: LE_y))
          LStoLE_lay.path = path4.cgPath
           
          let LEtoLW_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          LEtoLW_lay.lineWidth = 2.0
          LEtoLW_lay.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
          let path5 = UIBezierPath()
          path5.move(to: CGPoint(x: LE_x, y: LE_y))
          path5.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: LW_x, y: LW_y))
          LEtoLW_lay.path = path5.cgPath
           
          let LStoLH_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          LStoLH_lay.lineWidth = 2.0
          LStoLH_lay.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
          let path6 = UIBezierPath()
          path6.move(to: CGPoint(x: LS_x, y: LS_y))
          path6.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: LH_x, y: LH_y))
          LStoLH_lay.path = path6.cgPath
           
          let RStoRH_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          RStoRH_lay.lineWidth = 2.0
          RStoRH_lay.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
          let path7 = UIBezierPath()
          path7.move(to: CGPoint(x: RS_x, y: RS_y))
          path7.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: RH_x, y: RH_y))
          RStoRH_lay.path = path7.cgPath
           
          let RKtoRH_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          RKtoRH_lay.lineWidth = 2.0
          RKtoRH_lay.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
          let path8 = UIBezierPath()
          path8.move(to: CGPoint(x: RK_x, y: RK_y))
          path8.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: RH_x, y: RH_y))
          RKtoRH_lay.path = path8.cgPath
           
          let LKtoLH_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          LKtoLH_lay.lineWidth = 2.0
          LKtoLH_lay.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
          let path9 = UIBezierPath()
          path9.move(to: CGPoint(x: LK_x, y: LK_y))
          path9.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: LH_x, y: LH_y))
          LKtoLH_lay.path = path9.cgPath
           
          let RKtoRA_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          RKtoRA_lay.lineWidth = 2.0
          RKtoRA_lay.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
          let path10 = UIBezierPath()
          path10.move(to: CGPoint(x: RK_x, y: RK_y))
          path10.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: RA_x, y: RA_y))
          RKtoRA_lay.path = path10.cgPath

          let LKtoLA_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          LKtoLA_lay.lineWidth = 2.0
          LKtoLA_lay.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
          let path11 = UIBezierPath()
          path11.move(to: CGPoint(x: LK_x, y: LK_y))
          path11.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: LA_x, y: LA_y))
          LKtoLA_lay.path = path11.cgPath        

          let RHtoLH_lay = CAShapeLayer()
          RHtoLH_lay.lineWidth = 2.0
          RHtoLH_lay.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
          let path12 = UIBezierPath()
          path12.move(to: CGPoint(x: RH_x, y: RH_y))
          path12.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: LH_x, y: LH_y))
          RHtoLH_lay.path = path12.cgPath
       
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(RStoRE_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(REtoRW_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(LStoLE_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(LEtoLW_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(RStoLS_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(RStoRH_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(LStoLH_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(RKtoRH_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(RKtoRA_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(LKtoLH_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(LKtoLA_lay)
          imageView1.layer.addSublayer(RHtoLH_lay)
        }
      }catch{
        print("error")
      }
    }
  }
}
```